# Want to compare two columns of dataset and if true get the corresponding other columns from other dataset and find mean

Tags: python, pandas

want to compare 2 different columns which are getting like this format

in student_answer there are different values from 20th column to 43rd column
in did_he_answer there is a string 'Yes' or 'No' like that

now i shd traverse through 1st column of student_answer and then did_he_answer and if that logic as we see in `question answered correctly` it will calculate sum of the values in the dataframe

now in the time analysis part for all the indexes where that case was true those all's mean should be stored in a new column named `dataset['Average Time Taken for Correct Answer']`

how to do it

```
# general Info
dataset['Passed'] = np.where(dataset['Score']>=dataset['Cutoff Score'], 'Yes', 'No')
dataset['Time Taken'] = dataset['Attempt Time Taken (seconds)']/60
dataset['Average Time Taken'] = (dataset.iloc[:, 45:69]/60).mean(axis=1)
dataset['Your Rank'] = dataset['Score'].rank(ascending=False)

# values segregation
student_answer = dataset.iloc[:, 20:44].values
did_he_answer = dataset.iloc[:, 69:93]
time_taken_to_answer = dataset.iloc[:, 45:69]

# score analysis
dataset['Total Questions Answered'] = (did_he_answer == "No").sum(axis=1)
dataset['Questions Answered Correctly'] = ((student_answer == 5) & (did_he_answer == "Yes")).sum(axis=1)
dataset['Questions Answered Incorrectly'] = ((student_answer == 0) & (did_he_answer == "Yes")).sum(axis=1)
dataset['Question Answered Partially Correctly'] = (((student_answer > 2) & (student_answer < 5)) & (did_he_answer == "Yes")).sum(axis=1)
dataset['Questions Not Answered'] = (did_he_answer == "No").sum(axis=1)


# time analysis
correct_answer_indices = np.where((student_answer == 5) & (did_he_answer == 'Yes'))
print(correct_answer_indices)
dataset['Average Time Taken for Correct Answer'] = time_taken_to_answer[correct_answer_indices].mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
dataset['Average Time Taken for Correct Answer'] = np.nanmean(np.where((student_answer == 5) & 
                                                                       (did_he_answer == 'Yes'), 
                                                             time_taken_to_answer, None), axis=1)
```

Comment: this is not working i have tried this way already i got some other error for the last one and this method too gives some error 

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: @Nugget can you test `np.where((student_answer == 5) & 
                                                                       (did_he_answer == 'Yes'), 
                                                             time_taken_to_answer, None)` ? Because `NoneType` obviously means some wrong used `inplace`, so e.g. `print (student_answer )` is `NoneType`, not DataFrame.

Comment: this is the output i got

```
[[None None None None None 47 None 11 None None None None 101 None 95 53
  None 14 None None 13 None None 80]

...

```

when i printed out 
```
print(np.where((student_answer == 5) & (did_he_answer == 'Yes'), time_taken_to_answer, None))
```